# How to subtract each row of a pandas DataFrame from a number?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subtraction

Say I have a DataFrame:

```
ds = pd.DataFrame(np.abs(randn(3, 4)), index=[1,2,3], columns=['A','B','C','Average'])
ds
      A         B         C      Average
1  1.099679  0.042043  0.083903  0.410128
2  0.268205  0.718933  1.459374  0.758887
3  0.680566  0.538655  0.038236  1.169403
```

How do I subtract (and replace with the result) A, B and C in row one with the average in row 1?

Comment: first example in the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/basics.html#matching-broadcasting-behavior

Answer (score 3):

One relatively simple way is to use the `sub` method (I'm assuming that `Average` is always the last column):

```
ds[ds.columns[:-1]].sub(ds.Average, axis=0)
```

This does the following:

- `ds[ds.columns[:-1]]` is a DataFrame containing all but the last column (`Average`) of `ds`.
- `.sub(ds.Average, axis=0)` subtracts the row-values in the `Average` column from the corresponding rows in the DataFrame.

To alter your original `ds`, make sure to rebind the relevant columns of `ds` to the new DataFrame of values:

```
ds[ds.columns[:-1]] = ds[ds.columns[:-1]].sub(ds.Average, axis=0)
```

Comment: Axis = 0 is for column-wise operations. I think the correct answer would be ```axis=1```

Comment: It's a while since I answered this question, but reading it again it sounds like OP wanted a result with `(A - Average)`,  `(B - Average)` and `(C - Average)`, so I think the original answer with column-wise subtraction (`axis=0`) is correct.

Comment: Indeed Alex, I searched it a bit more. But I wanted to leave the comment for anyone wondering why we use ```axis=0``` based on the ```sub()``` documentation. Kudos :)

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
ds['A'] = ds['A'] - ds['Average']
ds['B'] = ds['B'] - ds['Average']
ds['C'] = ds['C'] - ds['Average']
```

Pandas is easy like that!

Oh, that does it for the entire DF. You only want it for the firs row is that right?

```
ds.loc[1, 'A'] = ds.loc[1, 'A'] - ds.loc[1, 'Average']
ds.loc[1, 'B'] = ds.loc[1, 'B'] - ds.loc[1, 'Average']
ds.loc[1, 'C'] = ds.loc[1, 'C'] - ds.loc[1, 'Average']
```

or in a loop:

```
for col in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
    ds.loc[1, col] = df.loc[1, col] - ds.loc[1, 'Average']
```

and so on...

if you have thousands of columns then simply do:

```
for col in ds.columns:
    ds[col] = ds[col] - ds['Average']
```

Comment: No I want it for the entire dataframe, and it has thousands of rows and columns.. is there an easier way to do it without naming the column names explicitly? df.columns.values or something like that?